# Creating a sub image in Java

Tags: java, image

I have an image 800x480. How do I create a new sub image of the following coordinates?

> 115, 235, 580, 202 (x, y, width, height)

Comment: Everything is possible. What did you try so far?

Comment: thank you Norman, private Image createImage(){
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(800,480,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) bi.getGraphics();
 g.fillRect(0, 0, bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight());

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the `BufferedImage`, do the following to get a subimage:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("yourPath"));
BufferedImage subimage = img.getSubimage(115, 235, 580, 202);
ImageIO.write(subimage, "png", new File("outputPath"));
```

This example works with the filesystem, you could also use streams.

[JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)):

```
public BufferedImage getSubimage(int x, int y, int w, int h)
```

**Parameters:**
x - the X coordinate of the upper-left corner of the specified rectangular region
y - the Y coordinate of the upper-left corner of the specified rectangular region
w - the width of the specified rectangular region
h - the height of the specified rectangular region

Comment: would that not lead to an image with tons of blank space?

Comment: Well it depends on the original image you are creating the sub-image from, since the original is 800x400 the sub-image is within the bounds:img.getSubimage(115, 235, 580, 202)

Comment: I just tried to apply this to my own project and my subimage is not intended to have the same bounds as the original. it is only 5% of the original size. So now I search for a way to make it smaller.

Comment: This code is cutting out a part of the original image, not scaling/resizing the original image.

Comment: yes. But I thought asking if it was possible so resize the image once you use the getSubimage() method was possible in a convienent way.